# Retrieve the WPA2 Enterprise username in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I have an interesting requirement that I'm not sure is even possible. Currently, I'm developing an iPad app for a fleet of tablets. The tablets connected to a WPA2 Enterprise WIFI network. Is it possible using Objective-C or Swift or C magic or whatever is necessary to get the identity/username that is connected to the wireless network?

I've poked around `CaptiveNetwork`, but it doesn't seem to be what I want. I'm not sure if there is something to `CWNetwork`, but that seems to be Mac only. You can do this on Android (I know, because I'm currently doing it with the key `android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration$EnterpriseField`).

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some reading and was thinking this would be possible through SCPreferences in the SystemConfiguration framework, but unless your device is jailbroken, the APIs you need are not available on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that comes to mind is with an MDM such as AirWatch or Good.